# Result of Variable needs Formatting in ColdFusion

Tags: variables, coldfusion, formatting

Using ColdFusion, if the result of a variable is not correctly formatted when rendered, how do I change it? For example, i have a variable `#number#` and its displayed value is `,3642,` but I want it to be displayed like `3642` instead.

How can I achieve this formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace all non-numeric characters with a regular expression.

```
<!--- Your original variable --->
<cfset input = ",3642," />

<!--- This is your solution --->
<cfoutput>#rereplaceNocase(input,'[^0-9]','','all')#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is sort of open-ended.  There are several string formatting functions depending on what you're trying to do, e.g. NumberFormat, DecimalFormat, YesNoFormat, Mid, etc etc.  Aaron's answer is good for the example you gave, but depending on what other examples you might have, you may need an alternative.  One generic way would be to have your own formatting function that does what you need.  And then either change the value of your variable, or just use the formatting function to change it when output.
e.g.

```
<cfset yourvariable = yourFormattingFunction(yourvariable)>

<cffunction name="yourFormattingFunction" output="false" hint="Does some custom formatting for your requirements">
  <cfargument name="somevariable" required="true">

  <cfset var newvariable = arguments.somevariable>

  <!--- do something to newvariable  --->
  <cfreturn newvariable>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#yourvariable#</cfoutput>
```

or

```
<cffunction name="yourFormattingFunction" output="false" hint="Does some custom formatting for your requirements">
  <cfargument name="somevariable" required="true">

  <cfset var newvariable = arguments.somevariable>

  <!--- do something to newvariable  --->
  <cfreturn newvariable>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>#yourFormattingFunction(yourvariable)#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i would like to ask you the question, why the return has unwanted characters, If you dont need it ever, clean the variable at the server side itself before returning

If thats not possible then consider using some of the below techniques

- Use Regex to remove the unwanted characters
- if that extra value(,) is always fixed use `ListChangeDelims(",3642,","","," );`